# LINEST gives #VALUE! error for some data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm wondering if anyone has any tips for using LINEST in Excel (2010). It's easy to find guides but difficult to get help troubleshooting. This may not be exactly the right forum but everyone's so helpful around here I can't resist asking.

I'm trying to use the Excel LINEST function to fit a third-order polynomial to a set of data.

`X_List: 44.00   45.50   46.30   46.80   47.50   47.90   48.60   49.90   51.20   51.80   52.30   53.00   53.40   54.30   55.70`

Y_List: 0.10    1.00    3.00    5.00    10.00   15.00   25.00   50.00   75.00   85.00   90.00   95.00   97.00   99.00   99.90

The LINEST equation I'm using is: `=LINEST(Y_LIST, X_LIST^{1,2,3})`

This invariably gives me a #VALUE! error when I use `^{1,2,3}` or `^{1,2}` but not `^{1}`. This same formula works with another data set so I know it's not a typo issue, and when I make a chart of the data and apply a trendline, it gives me a formula, so it should be able to calculate *something*. It does this regardless of whether or not I use the "array" entry method, i.e. ctrl-shift-enter with a selected range.

I figure either there's some problem with my numbers that I don't understand, or possibly that the syntax has changed from Excel 2007 such that the `^{1,2,3}` bit no longer works the way I expect.

Comment: did you enter the array formula with ctrl-SHIFT-enter, i.e. do you see these brackets `{}` around the formula?

Comment: Yeah, I typed "ctrl-enter" above where I meant to write "ctrl-shift-enter." I fixed it in the question. They do appear, so the array formula doesn't seem to be a problem in itself.

Answer (score 9):

Your formula should work if `Y_LIST` and `X_LIST` are **columns** of data of equal length - if they are **rows** of data try changing {1,2,3} to {1;2;3}, i.e.

`=LINEST(Y_LIST, X_LIST^{1;2;3})`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem just recently, linest was returning a `#VALUE` error for certain sets of data.  In my case, I was fitting a quadratic polynomial to the data, using `=LINEST(B2:B12,A2:A12^{0,1,2})`.  But, sneakily, one of my values in column A was 0, so Excel tried to do `0^0`, which gave a `#NUM`, which resulted in the `#VALUE` for `LINEST`.

I could have solved this by actually calculating in the sheet the `x^2` values and filling in the 1 values to go along with my x's in column A.  Instead, I went with an `IFERROR` function to catch the `#NUM` and return 1, `=LINEST(B2:B12,IFERROR(A2:A12^{0,1,2,3,4,5,6},1))`.

Not strictly related to OP's issue, but if you're looking for linest tips...

Answer (score 2):

I had this when one of the rows was blank. Blank rows work fine with the trendline (it ignores them) but `LINEST` simply shows `#VALUE!` until I deleted all the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

Argh. This turned out to be some problem Excel had with how it was classifying the data behind my back. I loaded these numbers in from a tab-separated text file and though I specifically changed the format of the cells to "Number," it still seemed to be treating them as something weird. I manually re-typed the same numbers elsewhere in the sheet and it worked fine.

It's tempting to complain about Excel at times like this but it definitely beats graph paper, pencil, and calculator. Most of the time.

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: If the numbers are text-formatted then you can't convert to number format just by changing the formatting - you could do that with "text to columns" though....or you can do it within the formula - using ^{1,2,3} should convert the X_LIST anyway, you could use +0, for example to convert the Y_LIST, so without manually re-typing this should work `=LINEST(Y_LIST+0,X_LIST^{1,2,3})`

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is having a problem with linest in mac 
try

```
1)  =(linest(select y, select x, true/false, true)

2) enter 

3 click on the value appeared press ctrl U

4) select your cells 

5) press ctrl shift return in mac keyboard
```

you should be able to get your answer

cheers